# Layer zPosition has no effect

Tags: ios, swift

Three layers are given the same parent, but the zPosition value on the first layer to be added has no effect - it remains at the back. Why is this? The book I'm reading says that the position in the sublayers array can be overridden with the zPosition value.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

extension CGRect {
    init(_ x:CGFloat, _ y:CGFloat, _ w:CGFloat, _ h:CGFloat) {
        self.init(x:x, y:y, width:w, height:h)
    }
}

let v0 = UIView(frame: CGRect(0, 0, 500, 500))
v0.backgroundColor = .white

let v1 = UIView(frame: v0.frame)

let lay1 = CALayer()
lay1.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0.4, blue: 1, alpha: 1).cgColor
lay1.frame = CGRect(113, 111, 132, 194)
lay1.zPosition = 100
v1.layer.addSublayer(lay1)

let lay2 = CALayer()
lay2.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 1, blue: 0, alpha: 1).cgColor

lay2.frame = CGRect(41, 56, 132, 194)
v1.layer.addSublayer(lay2)

let lay3 = CALayer()
lay3.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).cgColor
lay3.frame = CGRect(43, 197, 160, 230)
v1.layer.addSublayer(lay3)

v0.addSubview(v1)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = v0
```

Comment: what if you set the others zposition ? For layer 2, `lay2.zPosition = 90` and layer 3 `lay3.zPosition = 80` ?

Comment: Have you tried refactoring to use `view.bringSubview(toFront:)`? Seems like that should work.

Comment: @GIJOW No, that doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 3):

I think your code is working as expected. I just changed the colors of the view to

```
lay1.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
lay2.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
lay3.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
```

This is the output. You can see green view(lay1) which has z position is at the top.

[image]

Also , had fun playing with literals here:

[image]

Comment: @IanWarburton: You mean the output is not as you expected?

Comment: Try to zap derived data, deinstall the application from the simulator / device and try again

Comment: It works in an app. Seems that it's a problem with Playground.

Comment: @PuneetSharma How do you enter those literals?

Comment: XCode->Editor->Insert Color Literal. It will insert a color literal. Double tap on it to open the color picker.

Answer (score 0):

Code works as expected in an app. Seems that it's an issue with Playground.